# Calling new Form by clicking an item on the ListBox

Tags: c#

I'm a student and I'm still new in software programming. I have a listbox in my form and in my listbox box there are item or name listed example "Eric, Molly, Mel" and when I click "Eric", it should redirect me to a new form containing more information about "Eric". How can I call new form using the item listed in the listbox?

Comment: Don;t forget to mark the best suited reply as Answer!

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using WinForms to develop your project and you have a form called `Form1` with a ListBox called `listBox1` on it, you can do like that:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    listBox1.Click += OnListBoxItemClick;
}

private void OnListBoxItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form2 = new Form2(listBox1.SelectedItem);
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Your class `Form2` has to have a constructor which accepts the selected item as parameter.

Comment: Since Eric is new to programming and so am I, I think its best to add [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx) here just in case he's not familiar with overriding the constructor.

Comment: About the event created in this line of code `listBox1.Click += OnListBoxItemClick;
` I prefer using Visual Studio to create that stuff in the design partial class, and i cant find that _OnListBoxItemClick event_. So suggest selecting the `listBox1` control, go to the _property pane_, select the _event tab_ and scroll down to the _Click event_ and double click it. Eric, you can also check all the other events for the listBox that might suit you better.

Comment: @FernandoSilva: There is no need to override the constructor. This is the default constructor, a **must** for the designer, because in method `InitializeComponent` the controls are loaded and set with the properties of the property sheet of the designer.

Comment: Nice to know, i had a similar issue, but i needed to create a handle to the new form, and i created an overriden constructor that allowed to add the mainForm as a paramater, but the original/paramaterless constructor had to remain. I'll test it later to see if there are any errors to my code if i dont override. Either way its good to know i can just adapt my constructor instead of overriding it.

Comment: @FernandoSilva: If you write a special constructor for your form, you either have to call the default constructor or method InitializeComponent to have the form running correctly.

Comment: I just thought you needed to have this constructor `public Form2() {InitializeComponent();}` then add `public Form2(type objectName) {InitializeComponent(); //Do something with objectName}`. I didnt know you could delete the first constructor and just keep the second. Im quite new to programming, so maybe this is obvious, but i didnt know, it worked how i was told so i thought it was the right way. So thks for clearing that up for me ;D

Comment: @Eric: So it would be nice, if you accept one of the answers ... see [faq]

Comment: @Fischermaen If you want to try a diferent way to get that to work, i made a question about it on "programmers", take a look. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/127251/implications-of-handles-between-forms

Answer (score 1):

1. Create `Windows Forms Application.
2. Put `ListBox` control on the form.
3. Bind some data source to your `ListBox` control.
4. Create new `Form` called `PersonDetailsForm` whitch can show details of the person data record.
5. Subscribe to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.
6. Put such code to the event handler:

   ```
   PersonDetailsForm detailsForm = new PersonDetailsForm();
   detailsForm.PersonDataItem = listBox1.SelectedItem; // here is your info about person
   detailsForm.ShowDialog();
   ```

Comment: by the way can u ask more how can i put the name of the item that i click in the top of the form or it would become the header of the form, example i click "Eric", Eric now will become the name or the header of the newly called form.

Comment: @Eric `detailsForm.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem;` would change the detailsForm header to the selected item.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the "ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged" Event. You should also notice the difference between the Click Event and the one that i mentioned above.

For more information here is the [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I provide an example on my blog entitled

[C#: How to Load a Winform ComboBox or ListBox and have a Unique Value Associated with the Selected Item](http://omegacoder.com/?p=701)

[C# Winforms and the Hidden Association Tag](http://omegacoder.com/?p=66)

Both which can be used... But the gist of it is that you either load the object Tag with the form and when its selected, launch that or have a specialized dictionary which holds the form as well. For a full example see the above links.

HTH