# Open new form after selecting item on listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listbox and a button on my form. Listbox contains of 3 elements: House, People, Outdoor.
I have also created 3 forms to represent the values from the listbox.

I would like to user to highlight the item on the listbox and after clicking the button I would like to open the form selected by the user.

How can I achieve this? I have tried this link: [Calling new Form by clicking an item on the ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645896/calling-new-form-by-clicking-an-item-on-the-listbox) but without any success.

I have tried:

```
public Select()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listBox1.Click += OnListBoxItemClick;
        }


        private void OnListBoxItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var form2 = new House();
            House.ShowDialog();
        }
```

1. This would only allow me to open one form. How can I assigned different forms to be open with different values from listbox?
2. I would like the form to open after I click on the button, not the value in the listbox, how to achieve it?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried and what problems you ran into?

Comment: What do you mean "without any success"? All you have to do is wire the event handler and call Show (or ShowDialog), as the question you linked show. What's wrong?

Comment: Should be `form2.ShowDialog();`. See Mark's example for different forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use the ListBox's [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditem.aspx) Property:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
    {
        case "House":
            House h = new House();
            h.ShowDialog();
            break;
        case "People":
            People p = new People();
            p.ShowDialog();
            break;
        case "Outdoor":
            Outdoor o = new Outdoor();
            o.ShowDialog();
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried it, but nothing is happening. No errors, but no results either

Comment: @jaspernorth have you tried putting in breakpoints at the switch statement to see what `SelectedItem` is?

Comment: I have tried inserting MessageBox.Show(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()); at the top of button1_Click but again, nothing is happening. Do I need to initialize it somehow?

Comment: @jaspernorth It sounds like you are not subscribed to the `Click` event. Go to button1 in the Designer, go to the Events tab, and set the `Click` event to use `button1_Click`.

Comment: @jaspernorth You need to add the click event to your button in your designer or add it to the Button in your Constructor. Try putting a breakpoint on the button1_click event to see if it is being hit.

Comment: @jszigeti It worked! Thanks for your contribution and patience. I'm quite new to programming, and this silly thing would probably take me ages to solve. Thanks again

Comment: @MarkHall thank you for your answer. This is precisely what I needed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Dictionary` to map the values in your selected items to forms, or perhaps better yet functions that can create a form (to ensure lazy loading).

```
private Dictionary<string, Func<Form>> formMapping 
    = new Dictionary<string, Func<Form>>()
    {
        {"House", ()=> new House()},
        {"People", ()=> new People()},
        {"Outdoor", ()=> new Outdoor()},
    };
```

Then you can use that mapping in the click event handler to translate the selected value into a form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form newForm = formMapping[listBox1.SelectedValue]();
    newForm.ShowDialog();
}
```