# How do I make links in listBox clickable in C#

Tags: c#

I made an chat application that uses listBox and each time someone sends a new message the text is displayed in the list box, I want to make so if someone sends either message starting with http or https to be clickable and open the link in an default browser. I use Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise. I tried searching the web but didn't find what I was looking for and I have no idea how to do it myself. Any help highly appreciated.

EDIT: I want to make links clickable that are displayed in an listBox [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh2Bi.png) its an win forms application

Comment: is this a web or desktop application???

Comment: You can maybe use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://google.com"); to open the link after you get it as string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580263/how-to-open-in-default-browser-in-c-sharp.

Comment: Hey, please add a little bit more information about the context. Your question doesn't help to illustrate the situation. Fix the tag and briefly describe which platform you are working on before someone gives a downvote and demotivates you.

Comment: ill edit my question

Answer (score 0):

**1. Get the selected item as string -** `listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();` https://stackoverflow.com/a/18065641/13028588

**2. Find word that has http:// or https://**  C# - Maybe this can help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/search-strings
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-5.0
[Find text in string with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709821/find-text-in-string-with-c-sharp)

**3. After you get the link as string you can use this -**`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://thelink.com");` - [How to open in default browser in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580263/how-to-open-in-default-browser-in-c-sharp)

This is just to point you in the right direction hopefully.

Comment: can you explain the first step better, also the second step doesnt work anymore, or its just me, if i try to do process.start("link"); it throws an error in visual studio and doesnt work

Comment: Do you have  using System.Diagnostics; in the class

Comment: yes, i used it before and it threw an error with process.start if i've put a link in it, the last time i did was make an batch file and write into it Start "link" and it worked

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(" https://thelink.com "); Works in WinForms. I have used it and it works. About the batch file I dont understand because this is not Winforms this is CMD.

Comment: yeah, process.start didnt work because i was in c# console app i think, sorry